# My useEffect hook is not working when I'm changing the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

What it did is I fetched some products data in context using `useEffect` and stored the fetched data in a state.

Context Component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ProductContext from "./product-context";

const ProductContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [Products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/");
      console.log("hi");
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something Went Wrong");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setProducts(data);
    };

    fetchedData().catch((error) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoading: isLoading, products: Products }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProductContextProvider;
```

Now I used this context in my dynamic route that I have created
Routing Component

```
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import ProductDetails from "../Pages/ProductDetails";
import Home from "../Pages/Home";
import { useContext } from "react";
import ProductContext from "../Store/product-context";

const AnimatedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const ctx = useContext(ProductContext);
  const products = ctx.products;

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="/products/:productId"
          element={<ProductDetails items={products} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default AnimatedRoutes;
```

And now attach below is `<ProductDetails/>` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "../Components/Navigaiton-Bar/NavBar";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.productId;
  const product = props.items.find((pro) => pro.id === +id);

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Card>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap">
          <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[100vh] ">
            <div className="m-10">
              <img
                className="w-[800px] h-[300px]"
                alt="gallary"
                src={product.image}
              ></img>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{product.title}</p>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <p>{product.description}</p>
              <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Now the problem here is when I'm visiting my dynamic page i.e. for example, `"/products/1"` directly through url. My `useEffect` is not fetching any data. And my Products state is an empty array.

Comment: Where is `ProductContextProvider` being used and rendered so its `useEffect` hook can be called? The `useEffect` hook also has an empty dependency array, so it's only guaranteed to be called only once when `ProductContextProvider` mounts. Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] with all the relevant code you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the context in a wrong way. Assuming the Provider is in the root parent you can already access the context directly inside

```
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.productId;
  const ctx = useContext(ProductContext);
  const products = ctx.products;
  const product = products.find((pro) => pro.id === id);

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Card>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap">
          <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[100vh] ">
            <div className="m-10">
              <img
                className="w-[800px] h-[300px]"
                alt="gallary"
                src={product.image}
              ></img>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{product.title}</p>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <p>{product.description}</p>
              <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

You no longer need to pass the the product context on the route file

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue with the `useEffect` hook in `ProductContextProvider` that the OP is asking about. It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've copy/pasted your code into a running sandbox and the only way I can reproduce the issue you describe is if I ***manually*** edit the URL path in the address bar to navigate directly to any `"/products/:productId"` path.

## Issue

The issue is that the `ProductDetails` component doesn't handle correctly when there is no matched product by `id` property found. When the app mounts and is rendering the `"/products/:productId"` route and `ProductDetails` component, the `useEffect` hook hasn't run yet to fetch the data. The result is that `product` is undefined (*because keep in mind that `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` when no matching array element is found*) and the UI is attempting to access properties of a null/undefined value. This throws an exception.

## Solution

Update the `ProductDetails` component to handle missing, or not-found, data, which includes when it's initially fetching it for the first time. Conditionally return alternative UI when there is no product data to display.

Here's a trivial example:

```
const ProductDetails = ({ items }) => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = items.find((pro) => String(pro.id) === productId);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No product data.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Card>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap">
          <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[100vh] ">
            <div className="m-10">
              <img
                className="w-[800px] h-[300px]"
                alt="gallary"
                src={product.image}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{product.title}</p>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <p>{product.description}</p>
              <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit my-useeffect-is-not-working-when-im-changing-the-route]

### Suggestions

You could further enhance the UI/UX by including that `isLoading` state in the `ProductContextProvider` component and conditionally render a loading indicator/spinner/etc in the UI, ***and then*** conditionally render the above fallback or product UI once the data has been fetched.

The `useEffect` hook logic is a little off. `fetchedData` starts a Promise chain and sets `isLoading` true, but then immediately sets `isLoading` back to false on the next line which runs before the fetch is made and the Promise chain settles.

- Update the initial `isLoading` state to be true, for the cases when the component is initially mounted.
- Return the fetched `data` from the `fetchedData` function.
- Use the returned Promise from `fetchedData` to chain the thenables, using the `.finally` block to clear the loading state.

```
const ProductContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/");

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something Went Wrong");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    };

    fetchedData()
      .then(setProducts)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log({ error });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ isLoading, products }}>
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const AnimatedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<ProductDetails />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

```
const ProductDetails = ({ items }) => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const { isLoading, products } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const product = products.find((pro) => String(pro.id) === productId);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading Data</div>;
  }

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No product data</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Card>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap">
          <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[100vh] ">
            <div className="m-10">
              <img
                className="w-[800px] h-[300px]"
                alt="gallary"
                src={product.image}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{product.title}</p>
              <p>${product.price}</p>
              <p>{product.description}</p>
              <button>Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit my-useeffect-is-not-working-when-im-changing-the-route (forked)]